# Play Framework gather img src from database

Tags: html, scala, web, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to display an image which path is gathered from a database while using the Playframework.

The normal way to gather img src is via the assets route right?:

```
@routes.Assets.at
```

To get the img src I need to do this:

```
@champion.getIcon
```

So in total I want something like this:

```
@supports.map { champion =>
    <img src="@routes.Assets.at(@champion.getIcon)" alt="@champion.getName" />
}
```

Obviously this is not working, so I am asking how to do this instead. Of course I could change the img srcs in the database to the asserts/images/... but I think this is not the optimal solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the second `@` here:

```
@routes.Assets.at(@champion.getIcon)
```

The first `@` symbol lets the template compiler know that you're escaping for code, so while inside the method call for `.at(...)`, it is still understood that you're in the middle of a block of code. It is only until after the closing parenthesis, brace or space (depending on the context) would you have to re-open with another `@`.